# Can we find an example?

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples, fixed-point-theorems

I have this theorem, and i want to know if i can find an expression of the operator $A$ which satisfy this theorem:

[image]

Comment: It looks like an excerpt from some book. Can you find anything in the references?

Comment: no it's not from a book , i write this theorem

Comment: So you wrote a theorem and you ar asking us if we can find any application?

Comment: lol yes i prove it but i can't find an application so i ask if someone has an idea

Comment: @Siminore if i consider the operator $A$ defined on $H^{1}_0$ by  $Au(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) f(s,u(s))ds$ where $G(t,s)=\begin{cases} t(1-s),~~t\leq s\\s(1-t),~~s\leq t\end{cases}$ what can be the condition of $f$ to obtain that $A$ is continuously differentiable and how is defined $A'u(t)$ ? thank you